# Loopback to aux out and record audio at the same time from audio in

Tags: alsa, streaming, audio-playback, pulseaudio, radio

I am currently developing a device that silences adverts from a streaming radio. Im taking audio input from a radio to a USB sound card.To silence the ads, I have am currently using the arecord command to record (for the wav file to be sent for analysis):

```
arecord -D plughw:1,0 --duration=3 test.wav
```

and then I was planning to use the following command to stream out (loop out) to the USB sound card aux out which is connected to a speaker when there is a song playing

```
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1
```

then stop streaming out using the following command when there is an advert.

```
pactl unload-module $(pactl list short modules | awk '$2 =="module-loopback" { print $1}
```

Although recording and the loopback command works perfectly one their own, recording cant take place when the audio is being looped out.
Does anyone know how to configure the audio settings so that it will allow me to record wav files and loop out at the same time?

Comment: Use PulseAudio for recording, or ALSA's `dsnoop` plugin.